# Angular2 - Cant navigate to child elements in named outlets

Tags: angular, routes, angular2-routing, parent-child

I have a problem, for some reason I am not able to navigate to child elements that are located in named outlets. Here is how my code looks like.

app.component.ts

```
<router-outlet name="outlet"></router-outlet>
```

app.routes.ts

```
export const appsRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'parent',
        children: [
            { path: 'messages', component: MessagesComponent, outlet: 'outlet' },
        ]
    },

];
```

And here is how I navigate.

somepage.component.html

```
(click)="openAllMessages()"
```

somepage.component.ts

```
  openAllMessages() {
    this.router.navigate(['parent/messages', { outlets: outlet }}]);
  }
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: There are several issues regarding aux routes (named outlets) posted in the issues list in the Angular repo on github:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13006

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12086

Are these issues similar to what you are experiencing?

Comment: Yes, very similar. @DeborahK Basicly, if I navigate to a child route, it all works, if I navigate to a child route which should be displayed in namet outlet, it does not work.

Comment: @RahulSingh the error I get is 
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes.